# How to detect where an alert dialog is created in React Native android

Tags: android, react-native

After upgrading react native from 0.20 to 0.29 my app started generating random alert dialogs with undefined as text.

How do I find where the dialog was created so that I can debug it?
Where to put a breakpoint to see the stack?

Comment: It would be in the compiled android code... I'm not sure you would be able to set breakpoints there

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm seeing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Open `android` directory as a project in Android Studio, then find file `DialogModule`(**Include non-project files** option should be enabled), debug in method `showNewAlert`.

Comment: This allows me to intercept the alert dialog, but in the Java side i do not get any info about where it was generated. How can I do the same on the Javascript side?

Comment: @egiordano747 you can print what you put in dialog by `console.log()` and watch logcat in Android Studio by tag `ReactNativeJS`

Answer (score 0):

Well I haven't tried it in a real device. but it works in a regular browser so it's worth a try..
Put this code in the root of your application and [debug with chrome](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#debugging-on-a-device-with-chrome-developer-tools) (you could also try console.trace instead of the debugger):

```
window._alert = alert;
alert = function(data){debugger; window._alert(data)}
```